# Subnational data on corruption

Tags: data-request, government, global, latin-america

Any sub-national data on corruption (any form)? Interested in any nation, but primary interest in Central and South America.

Comment: I think it may help to expand this question. For example, are you interested in government, corporate, non-profit, etc corruption data? Please see [here](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/a/285/1511) for how to ask a good question.

Comment: Mostly interested in government corruption data. But other sources also be of interest.

Comment: I know of the [CPI]()http://www.transparency.org/cpi2014/in_detail) but it doesn't do anything intranational. It it what it is.